# How to make regular triangle mesh in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, mesh

I've searched without getting any success.
Is it possible create a regular triangle mesh in opencv ?

Comment: opencv is basically for computer vision. Maybe OpenMesh http://www.openmesh.org/ has some functionalities to create regular triangle meshes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've asked about opencv, because I want to apply a mesh into a binary image, which has holes.
I've been searching for effective ways to create a mesh having a image.

Comment: sorry, I don't get it: Do you want to create a mesh from an image (3d reconstruction), or do you want to create an image from mesh (rendering)? Better add some sample images and explain what you want to get. That will probably find some answers more likely than a 1-liner.

Comment: If you want to create a mesh from images, there are generally 2 steps: 1. reconstruction of sparse or dense points from a 2D image. 2. creating a triangle mesh from those reconstructed points. The first task is a computer vision task and the second one is more a computer graphics task. So it is more likely that opencv has functions to solve the first task than the second task BUT: OpenCV has a delauny triangulation function, afaik.

Comment: 2D mesh. I want to "mesh" a surface, 0 thickness.
For instance from here: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/710615/withframe.png to here:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/710615/tooverlay.jpg

the second image is not very fine, it is just to be more understandable

Comment: There are some python mesh generators. However, they need a list of facets and vertices (polygons) and holes. I don't know either to smart get it from a bitmap image.
Trimesh, Triangle generate from lists like this.

Comment: google delauny triangulation, find out whether that is what you need and if yes, openCV has a function to compute it =) maybe you'll need something like delauny refinement, too https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/tripaper/triangle4.html in that case, openCV probably won't help much.

Comment: have a look at that project page, too: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/tripaper/triangle0.html

Comment: for a 2D mesh generator you should only need vertices, I guess. Just use all the 2D points of the contour as vertices. you could threshold your image and findContours or use edge detection and findContours. (or just edge detection)

Comment: I've tried triangle too. But the results are not very good, probably the the 1st problem to solve is how to get a list of holes, faces, vertices.

Comment: use cv::findContours hierarchically. What do you mean by faces?

Comment: For instance, If you look at https://github.com/inducer/meshpy/blob/master/examples/test_triangle.py they ask for "facets".
I wrote faces, sorry !

Comment: google says that a facet is a part of a face (like a subdivision)? Imho that should be the result of a mesh generation, not the input. Typically you provide vertices (and holes) and the algorithm produces the mesh. But I don't have much practical experience in computer graphics, my information is from university lectures...

Comment: Micka how do I get the vertices ? And the "corners" How much points should I give to create it?

Comment: For example choose every contour pixel to be a vertex. You can choose `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` during contour extraction to reduce the number of contour pixels.

Comment: If I choose all the pixels, it won't be too much points?

Comment: you can choose any subset if you think there are too many. But from my point of view, the method which computes the regular mesh should automatically choose and remove vertices if error is low.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`cv::Subdiv2D`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/df/dbf/classcv_1_1Subdiv2D.html#aed58be264a17cdbe712b6a35036d13cb&gsc.tab=0) for triangulation. Here is a [link to C++ and Python examples](http://www.learnopencv.com/delaunay-triangulation-and-voronoi-diagram-using-opencv-c-python/).

But I think this implementation cannot handle holes, if I remember correctly.

I would also suggest that you check out the C-library [Triangle](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html). It allows you to specify holes besides many other useful things. Apparently, several [wrappers for Python](https://www.google.com/search?q=triangle+shewchuck+python) exist for it (but I have never used them).

Comment: I've tried subdiv2d, and it cannot handle holes :\ I think the 1st problem to solve is how to get a list of holes, faces, vertices.